# Code editor that supports regular expression lookbehind search

Tags: linux, gui, programming, regex, editor

I am currently using VSCode on Ubuntu, which does not currently support lookbehind in their search (although it is in the [pipelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60218)). Are there any GUI code editors for Linux that does support lookbehinds in search *right now*? (preferrably free, as in beer)

Comment: Sublime can do, but is not free. Should I add as answer anyway?

Comment: Can confirm that Sublime Text works with lookbehind (even negative lookbehind). Might as well add it, and I will remove the word 'free' from my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sublime

Sublime can handle lookahead and lookbehind.

```
abc
```

- Search for `(?<=a)b` finds b
- Search for `(?<=a)c` gives no results

Sublime is proprietary software.

> Sublime Text may be downloaded and evaluated for free, however a license must be purchased for continued use.

Answer (score 1):

### [Atom](https://atom.io/)

Lookbehind does not work, while lookahead works (?!).
But you can use `\K` in a similar manner.

```
abc
```

- Search for `(?<=a)b` gives **Invalid group error**.
- Search for `a\Kb` finds b.
- Search for `a\Kc` gives no results.
- Search for `b(?=c)` finds b.
- Search for `a(?=c)` gives no results

Comment: Thanks! Since `\K` is a Perl-flavoured regex, I tried the `\K` with the **Use PCRE2** option enabled in VSCode and it works! Do you have any idea how to do the same with negative lookbehind?

Answer (score 0):

### [Geany](https://geany.org/)

Geany can handle lookahead and lookbehind.

```
abc
```

- Search for `(?<=a)b` finds b
- Search for `(?<=a)c` gives no results

Comment: Geany is such an amazing piece of software.

Comment: I just downloaded Geany and tried a dummy command `grep -nHIrE -- (?<=d)ev (in directory: /path/to/dir)` and it didn't work. Do I have to install some kind of plugins?

Comment: I don't get it, where did you try this command?

Comment: I used the search functionality in Geany. This is the command that is printed out in the **Messages** tab at the bottom.

Comment: Did you use "Find in files" ? That uses `grep`, but normal find (Ctrl+F) does not print anything in Messages.

Comment: Yes, I tried with only Ctrl+F (search within file) and it works. Does not work with Ctrl+Shift+F (search for all files within project) though.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://ace.c9.io or http://lighttable.com also it would help if you told us what language you are coding in

Comment: Should he try or do you know if they can do it ?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what language I am coding in, they are all just text files.